What are the 1PI diagrams of $\phi^3$ theory?
When looking at propagators (so expressions sandwiched between vacuum states) the first order in the exponential expansion of the $\phi^3$ theory vanishes because it gives 5 fields, viz
$$\sim \langle 0| T\left\{ \phi(x) \phi(y) \phi(z)\phi(z)\phi(z) \right\}|0 \rangle, $$
and this means that we will always be left with a non-contracted field that will give $0$ when acted upon from the right and the left by the vacuum state.
I am now interested in deriving the one-particle irreducible diagrams needed to evaluate $S$-matrix elements, eg. $\langle \vec{p_3} \vec{p_4} | S | \vec{p_1} \vec{p_2} \rangle$. It seems to me that these 1PI’s will be in the first-order of the expansion, i.e. will have $\phi^3$ terms and not $\phi^6$ and higher. This leads me to two questions:

Will the 1PI diagram(s) come actually from terms proportional to $\phi^3$ or am I missing something?
How would I draw the diagram corresponding to an expression with a non-contracted field, eg. $\phi_a(x) \phi_b(y) \phi_a(z) \phi_b(z) \phi(z)$? The subscripts denote which fields are contracted together. So the last field on the right is not contracted.

FYI the diagrams I got for the 1PI are below. I'm new to this stuff so if what I did doesn't make sense please bare with me.


Comments to post (v3): 1. The diagrams on the RHS do not have the number of external legs of the diagram on the LHS. 2. There are infinitely many connected 1PI diagrams in $\phi^3$-theory. 3. Consider to clarify & focus the question.

Could someone explain to me why this question was closed and how can I make it clearer? This doesn't make any sense to me!!!
